# I am trying to query my firebase firestore by a text value in the collection, is this possible?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I would like to search by ticket number, but I don't even know if this is possible

[image]

```
  const GetSingleTicket = (id) => {
    // const ticketRef = collection(db, "form");

    const q = query(collection(db, "form"), where("form", "==", 3620));

    const querySnapshot = getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code queries this collection:

```
collection(db, "form")
```

But in the database screenshot it looks like the collection is called `Tickets`, so that'd be:

```
collection(db, "Tickets")
```

---

Second, your where clause is:

```
where("form", "==", 3620)
```

But in the database that value is stored in the field `TicketNumber`, so that'd be:

```
where("TicketNumber", "==", 3620)
```

---

I highly recommend spending some time in the Firestore documentation on [querying documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and the pages around it, as a bit of time spent there can save you a lot of time going forward.

Comment: I reuploaded an image,  apologies for uploading the wrong one.  I guess what I am talking about is possible a sub collection?   TicketNumber is inside of form, that is what I am having trouble accessing.   I appreciate the help and I really do need to do a better job with the documentation.  Thanks for the help

Comment: There is no field `TicketNumber` inside the `form` map in the document you're now showing, but if you want to filter on a subfield you can use `.` notation: `where("form.TicketNumber", "==", 3620)`